# Migration MYSQL to MYSQLi: DB function in output-buffer-handler not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am migrating a legacy project from `mysql_` to `mysqli_`.

Somewhere in the code there is

```
ob_start("do_output");
```

And in my

```
function do_output($output) { 
     [...]
     querydb(' .... ');
     [...]
}
```

where `querydb()` looks like thi

```
function querydb($query,$dieonerrors=true,$ec=false) {
    global $db_conn, $db_type, $debuginfos, $stat_qcount;
    ...
```

Now when I check this with the debugger `$db_conn` is `null`. It was initialized with `$db_conn = mysqli_connect()` earlier. And the connection was working during the run. But inside of the output buffer handler it became `null`. How can this be? With `mysql_*`it was working.

**EDIT** Here is the full code demonstrating the problem:

```
<?php

$db_type = "mysqli";
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_database = "test";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "root";

initdb();

querydb("SHOW TABLES");
ob_start('do_output');
querydb("SHOW TABLES");

echo "foobar";

function initdb($persistent = false)
{
    global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database, $db_type, $db_conn;
    $db_conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    mysqli_query($db_conn, "USE $db_database");
    return $db_conn;
}


function querydb($query, $dieonerrors = true, $ec = false)
{
    global $db_conn, $db_type, $debuginfos, $stat_qcount;
    $result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        if ($dieonerrors) {
            die('error');
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


function do_output($output)
{
    querydb('SHOW TABLES');  // if I comment this I get an output 'foo'
    return "foo";
}
```

I get no output and the error in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` is

```
PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/foo/bar/test.php on line 32
```

Comment: There is obviously more code to this, and many places where `query()` db (or other functions like it) are called. Somewhere `$db_conn` is being set to null, but it doesn't occur in the code you have posted.  Also, is `mysqli_connect()` called _inside_ a function? If so, is `$db_conn` made `global` there too so that it isn't bound to that connection function's scope?

Comment: I checked the code for such. With mysql instead of mysqli it worked fine. After the migration script it doesn't.

Comment: Please post the full contextual code where querydb() is called and the code where mysqli_connect is called.  It's implementation differs from mysql_connect especially in scoping